# Iterate over AWS Glue DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm quite new to AWS Glue and still trying to figure things out, I've tried googling the following but can't find an answer...

Does anyone know how to iterate over a DynamicFrame in an AWS Glue job script?

For example, I'm trying to do the following:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                        database = "...", 
                        table_name = "...", 
                        transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

for r in datasource0:
    print(r)
```

But receive the following error:

```
'DynamicFrame' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'DynamicFrame' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I think the `datasource0` is essentially a spark dataframe - so you can test out your code by trying things in local pyspark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert Glue's DynamicFrame into Spark's DataFrame and use [foreach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) function to iterate rows:

```
def f(row):
   print(row.name)

...

datasource0.toDF().foreach(f)
```

Comment: why aws glue is not running foreach(f) on spark dataframe?